# Error Dump Failed in QGIS plugin?

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins

Error "Dump Failed" minivolcado written in a temporary folder causes that my complement is closed which I am developing without finishing executing and closes QGis v.2.8.

What are these types of errors and what is happening so that it is generated?

Now uninstall QGis and delete all the folders and their registry, also delete the temporary files of the machine and reinstalled, but still giving the error.

Comment: These error occurs, when you are using Threading some some other background processing and QGIS memory overloads with some errors, and you are no more able to make contact with backgrounds processes. It's related to Disk I/O. You need to efficiently handle your code, in order to solve the issue.